# How to append all the columns into one column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to append the columns of a dataframe into one column via pandas library:

DF is the table:[image]

```
oneCol = []
colLength = len(finalDF)
for k in range(colLength):
    oneCol.append(DF[k])
combined = pd.DataFrame(oneCol)
combined
```

but the output is [image]

what I'm after is just one column dataframe.
Thank you.

Comment: This could also be achieved using stack() function of pandas. Refer https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas.DataFrame.stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
combined = pd.concat(oneCol, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you.